# Table headings not displayed correctly in fixed header scrolling table

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

Below is the fiddle, just click on the "Add Question" button 3 times and then the scroll bar would appear to the table:

http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/16/

The problem is the table headers cells do not match the cells of the rest of the columns. Now the class of the column cells for each `<th>` and `<td>` is the same but yet the width fo the cells are not the same and thus causes incorrect alignments between the cells going down the column.

Below is the html of the table:

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead class="tblhead">
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
    <th class="optandans">Option and Answer</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tblbody">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the main css which controls the table and each column:

```
body{
    font-size:85%;  
}           

.extratd{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.qid { 
    min-width:3%;
    max-width:3%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question { 
    min-width:14%;
    max-width:14%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question textarea {
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:auto;
    resize:none;
    height:100%;
    font-size:100%;
}

.noofanswers{
    min-width:15%;
    max-width:15%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.optandans{
    min-width:30%;
    max-width:30%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.option{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.answer { 
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
     }   

.tblbody{
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto; 
}

.tblhead, .tblbody {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious. Are you sure you are not `echo`-ing something before `echo $form`?

Comment: @user1830984 see my answer and let me if any issues you face in your code. I want to make you happy again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/51/

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/51/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div id="details">
    <table id="qandatbl" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="9%" class="qid">Question No</th>
          <th width="29%" class="question">Question</th>
          <th width="62%" class="optandans">Option and Answer</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="qandatbl_onthefly_container">
    <table id="qandatbl_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
#qandatbl_onthefly_container
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    max-height:600px;
}


#qandatbl, #qandatbl_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
#qandatbl
{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
}
#qandatbl_onthefly
{
    width:100%;
}

.qid {
    /*width:15%;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

/*.question {
    width:30%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}*/

.question {
    /*min-width:14%;
    max-width:14%;*/
    max-width:0.1%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
      line-height: 0;
}

.noofanswers{
    min-width:15%;
    max-width:15%;
    /*padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;*/
}

.optandans{
    /*min-width:30%;
    max-width:30%;*/
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.option{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    /*padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;*/
}

.answer {
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    /*padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;*/
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
function insertQuestion(form)
{
//updated variables

var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $td = $("<td class='extratd'  width='62%'>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid' width='9%'></td>").text(qnum);
    var $question = $("<td class='question' width='29%'></td>");

.................
 you function code here
.................

setWidth();

}

function setWidth() {
    var questionCellWidth = $("#qandatbl_onthefly tbody .question").width();
    console.log(questionCellWidth);
    var questionCellHeight = $("#qandatbl_onthefly tbody .question").height();
    console.log(questionCellHeight);
    $(".textAreaQuestion").css({
        "width": (questionCellWidth - 6) + "px",
        "height": (questionCellHeight) + "px"
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var flag = true;
    if(flag == true)
    {
        var tbl_qanda = $("#qandatbl").width();
        $("#qandatbl").css({"width": (tbl_qanda - 16)+ "px"});
    }
    var tbl_qanda_onthefly = $("#qandatbl_onthefly").width();
    if(tbl_qanda > tbl_qanda_onthefly)
    {
         $("#qandatbl").css({"width": (tbl_qanda_onthefly - 16)+ "px"});
         $("#qandatbl_onthefly_container").css({"width": (tbl_qanda_onthefly)+ "px"});
    }
});
```

**Note:** I have just created the scrolling functionality in this code and added functionality to scroll the table rows vertically see the **`setwidth()`** function which is setting the width of textarea and the **`$(document).ready(function(){});`**  function to see the scrolling functionality. Looks and feel is entirely up to you. You can fine tune the code as per your need.

Comment: Thanks again and you indeed made me very happy again Happy Singh :) Really like that name

Answer (score 1):

Give same CSS width value for the TH and TD.

Comment: This is what I tried previously but it did not work. Please look at this fiddle with your method http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/28/, you can see that it still doesn't align the cell in the columns